# Playback error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error

Tags: flutter, playback

When I want to seek to some duration in videoPlayer, It gives these errors and can not show the video from the position that I want:

```
I/System.out(28216): [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
I/System.out(28216): [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:644)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:616)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.read(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:489)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.read(DefaultDataSource.java:268)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.read(StatsDataSource.java:92)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorInput.readFromUpstream(DefaultExtractorInput.java:291)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorInput.read(DefaultExtractorInput.java:68)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ts.TsExtractor.fillBufferWithAtLeastOnePacket(TsExtractor.java:433)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ts.TsExtractor.read(TsExtractor.java:323)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.BundledHlsMediaChunkExtractor.read(BundledHlsMediaChunkExtractor.java:67)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaChunk.feedDataToExtractor(HlsMediaChunk.java:473)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaChunk.loadMedia(HlsMediaChunk.java:437)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaChunk.load(HlsMediaChunk.java:394)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:412)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):   Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$3.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:212)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:250)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:217)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:50)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream$ChunkedSource.read(Http1xStream.java:439)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:371)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.readInternal(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:777)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.read(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:487)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28216):       ... 14 more
```

This is how I initialize the player:

```
 Future<void> initializePlayer() async {
    _videoPlayerController1 = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.filmUrl);

    await Future.wait([
      _videoPlayerController1.initialize(),
    ]);
    //go to Last seconds of movie that has been watched by user
    await _videoPlayerController1.seekTo(const Duration(minutes: 20)); 

    _createChewieController();
    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {});
  }
```